# JavaFX 2: Tables: Update display after having updated data

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, repaint

This is all I need to finish answering [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234635/javafx-2-get-tablecell-row-index).

If you look at my last question, you will see my class, containing four fields, corresponding to the four columns of my table

```
public static class ContactOptions {

    private final StringProperty one;
    private final StringProperty two;
    private final StringProperty three;
    private final StringProperty four;

    ContactOptions(String col1, String col2, String col3, String col4) {
        this.one = new StringProperty(col1);
        this.two = new StringProperty(col2);
        this.three = new StringProperty(col3);
        this.four = new StringProperty(col4);
    }

    public String getOne() {
        return one.get();
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two.get();
    }

    public String getThree() {
        return three.get();
    }

    public String getFour() {
        return four.get();
    }
}
```

How do I get the GUI to update after I run `ContactOptions.one.set`?

When I scroll down and back up, it updates. How can I get it to update without scrolling.

I also asked this at https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2275725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use one of the methods below:

```
updateTableColumn(TableColumn col)
```

Updates the TableColumn associated with this TableCell.

```
updateTableRow(TableRow tableRow)
```

Updates the TableRow associated with this TableCell.

```
updateTableView(TableView tv)
```

Updates the TableView associated with this TableCell.

(From http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html)

But I think you had already handled this problem)

Comment: Yes, I have handled this item. But not using those methods. Looks like just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

For updates to work seamlessly, you should initialize each property and add the `xxxProperty` method:

```
private final StringProperty one = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public StringProperty oneProperty() {
   return one;
}
```

From my own experience, do not use property names using upperCase letters, like "myOne" or "myONE", as the `xxxProperty` method won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Which build of JavaFX 2.0 are you using? The reason I ask is that tables changed recently and I want to make sure you are using the latest version.